# Excel - copy cells+macro+VBA from one sheet to another?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to modify my spreadsheet so that when you click on the "insert worksheet" button, it adds the text, forms, VBA, Macro, etc from cells B38-K38:B52-K52 to a new worksheet and allows the user to click on the "Click Here" button I have and enter the data as desired.  I tried doing this with a VBA script but it is coming up with an error because everytime it adds a sheet, the number will go up.  Will incrementing fix this or is there another solution?

Edit, here's the solution:

```vb
Sub new_sheet()
    '
    ' new_sheet Macro
    ' Copies the range of B36:L52 (Problems Identified) to a new sheet
    ' Then resizes columns
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B36:L52").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Need a little more information. What code does the "click here" button run right now? Are you making copies of this button? Is the code attached to the button you are copying? What do you mean by "will incrementing fix this". Not enough information to answer this - please try to provide enough information that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit vague.  It has a "Click here" button that upon clicking, allows you to type in the inspection area which fills in the cell (B39) with that information.  The code is attached to the button, and I'm trying to copy the button (and its code) and cells to a new worksheet.  I meant incrementing the sheet name "Sheet++" might allow it to not have a debug error because the macro I tried making is looking for "sheet2", "sheet3", etc.

Comment: I guess for right now I can ignore the button as it's pretty unnecessary to begin with.  Even something as simple as copying a form and some simple formulas to a new sheet with a macro, it doesn't work properly.  It will just paste an image of what I have created.

Comment: If your code is in the worksheet module (not in a regular module) then it should copy over with the sheet.  If your code is in the sheet module you can use `Me` instead of (eg) `Sheet1` to refer to the sheet hosting the running code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple macro like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "NewSheet"
```

Will copy the active sheet and everything in it, and make a new one that is called "NewSheet". Would that help?

Comment: It would, but how would I go about only using information from a few cells?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out.  I used:

Sub new_sheet()
'
' new_sheet Macro
' Copies the range of B36:L52 (Problems Identified) to a new sheet
' Then resizes columns
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B36:L52").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

Comment: @gib - glad you figured it out. You might want to add your solution as an answer for the benefit of future visitors.